# Getting rid of an extra "Null" in an R Function

Tags: r, function

I've written a simple function in R (**see below**) which works well. But, I get an unwanted word: "**Null**" at the end of the output when I execute the code.

I was wondering how I could **modify my current code to remove** the the unwanted, extra word **"Null"** that appears at the end of the output given by this function?

Here is my **R code:**

```
postsigma <- function(n,sigma2,b2,mu,mean){

SigPost <- (1/((n/sigma2)+(1/b2)))
MuPost  <- ((SigPost/b2)*mu)+((SigPost/(sigma2/n))*mean)

curve(dnorm(x,MuPost,sqrt(SigPost)),xlim=c(0,MuPost+4),ylim=c(0,dnorm(MuPost,MuPost,sqrt(SigPost))+.02),ylab="Density",main=expression("Posterior of  "(mu)))
D <- cat("\t","Mu of Posterior:","\t",MuPost,"\n","\t","Sigma of Posterior:",SigPost)

return(D)}

postsigma(200,15,5,2,5)
```

Comment: Read the help page for `cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NULL is the value of D. R will print this out. Just remove the statement `return(D)` and it will get rid of the NULL.  You might also want to add a linefeed `\n` to your `cat` statement

Also  there is no reason to save the result of the `cat` in D.  You can leave off `D <-` as well.